# How to create a vector that implements the Map interface?

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to create a vector class that implements the Map interface, but in the put method it returns NullException, I need help implementing the put method, I can't find this type of content on the internet

```
public class Vetor_map implements Map<Key, Student> {


private int nElements;
private Map<Key, Student> mapa[];

public Vetor_map(int max) {
    mapa = new Map[max];
    nElements = 0;
    
}

// PUT
@Override
public Estudante put(Key key, Estudants value) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        mapa[nElements].put(key, value);
        nElements++;
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (nElements == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    if (nElements == mapa.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Class main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Key ch = new Key();
    Student es = new Student();
    Vetor_map vm = new Vetor_map(10);
    
    System.out.println("Key: " + ch + ", Estudant: "+ es);
    
    vm.put(ch, es);
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyrGy.png)

Comment: Well `mapa[nElements].put()` will result in a NPE because `mapa = new Map[max];` will only create the array but all elements will still be `null`. This should be easy to spot by using a debugger. One question though: vectors/lists and maps are different concepts, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm developing a work of data structure where I need to create a vector that implements the Map interface and calculate the execution time, I can insert the data in the map, but not the map in the vector

Comment: As I said you need to actually create the map elements in your array. However, I also still don't get why you need a "vector that implements the Map interface". Both are inherently different so having a list of maps with one element each doesn't make much sense. How would the `get(key)` method be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is a collection of entries where each [entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a key-value pair. So your `Vetor_map` class should implement `java.util.Map` – which it does – but I think that you should also create a class that implements interface `Map.Entry`.

In the below code, I added an inner class `VectorMapEntry` that implements `Map.Entry` and therefore class `VectorMap` – which implements interface `Map` – contains an array of `VectorMapEntry` instances. From there it is just a simple matter of implementing the methods of both interfaces, namely `Map` and `Map.Entry`.

Note the following in the below code.

1. I changed the name from `Vetor_map` to `VectorMap`.
2. I added methods `toString()` and `main()` to class `VectorMap` for testing purposes only. I also added method `toString()` to classes `Key` and `Student` also for testing purposes.
3. You did not supply code for classes `Key` and `Student` so I added skeleton definitions for those two classes. Note that each class – `Key` and `Student` – **must** each implement method [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). I only added method [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) since the *javadoc* for method `equals()` recommends doing so.
4. `VectorMap` cannot contain a null `Key` but it can contain a null `Student` as a value for a given `Key`.
5. Each `Key` in `VectorMap` is unique. When calling method `put()` with a `Key` that already exists in `VectorMap`, the existing value is replaced.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class VectorMap implements Map<Key, Student> {

    private static class VectorMapEntry implements Map.Entry<Key, Student> {
        private Key key;
        private Student student;

        public VectorMapEntry(Key k, Student s) {
            key = k;
            student = s;
        }

        public Key getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public Student getStudent() {
            return student;
        }

        public void setStudent(Student s) {
            student = s;
        }

        @Override
        public Student getValue() {
            return student;
        }

        @Override
        public Student setValue(Student value) {
            student = value;
            return value;
        }
    }

    private int nElements;
    private VectorMapEntry[] entries;

    public VectorMap(int initialSize) {
        if (initialSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial size must be positive.");
        }
        entries = new VectorMapEntry[initialSize];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return nElements;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return nElements == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (VectorMapEntry entry : entries) {
            if (entry == null) {
                break;
            }
            found = entry.getKey().equals(key);
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (VectorMapEntry entry : entries) {
            if (entry == null) {
                break;
            }
            found = entry.getStudent().equals(value);
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    @Override
    public Student get(Object key) {
        for (VectorMapEntry entry : entries) {
            if (entry == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                return entry.getStudent();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Student put(Key key, Student value) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key.");
        }
        boolean found = false;
        for (VectorMapEntry entry : entries) {
            if (entry == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                entry.setStudent(value);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            if (nElements == entries.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Map is full.");
            }
            entries[nElements] = new VectorMapEntry(key, value);
            nElements++;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Student remove(Object key) {
        int index = 0;
        Student s = null;
        for (VectorMapEntry entry : entries) {
            if (entry == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                s = entry.getStudent();
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        if (index < nElements) {
            for (int i = index; i < nElements - 1; i++) {
                entries[i] = entries[i + 1];
            }
            nElements--;
        }
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends Key, ? extends Student> m) {
        if (m != null) {
            m.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .forEach(ent -> put(ent.getKey(), ent.getValue()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            entries[i] = null;
        }
        nElements = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Key> keySet() {
        Set<Key> keySet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            keySet.add(entries[i].getKey());
        }
        return keySet;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Student> values() {
        Collection<Student> vals = new ArrayList<>(nElements);
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            vals.add(entries[i].getStudent());
        }
        return vals;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<Key, Student>> entrySet() {
        Set<Map.Entry<Key, Student>> entSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            entSet.add(entries[i]);
        }
        return entSet;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(entries[i].getKey());
            sb.append('=');
            sb.append(entries[i].getValue());
        }
        sb.append(']');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Key ch = new Key();
        Student es = new Student();
        VectorMap vm = new VectorMap(10);
        System.out.println("Key: " + ch + ", Estudant: "+ es);
        vm.put(ch, es);
        System.out.println(vm);
    }
}

class Key {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Key";
    }
}

class Student {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Student";
    }
}
```

Also note that it would be possible to change the above code such that `VectorMap` could (theoretically) contain an infinite number of key-value pairs. This could be achieved by simply enlarging the `entries` array whenever it gets completely filled.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will continue the work by following these steps.